# How to wrap a long text which has no whitespace in it

Tags: gwt, word-wrap

```
final jLabel descLabel = new jLabel();
des.setWordWrap(true);
des.setWidth("200px");
descLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
tableDisplay.setWidget(row, 2, des);
```

I'm placing the label inside a `FlexTable`

This is how it looks in the label. It's exceeding beyond the width I have given for the label.
Appears odd. I mean to say that the long text without whitespace is not following the width I have given for the label. Tried giving this:

```
public class Jlabel extends Label{
public  Jlabel () {
 DOM.setStyleAttribute(this.getElement(), "word-wrap", "break-word");
}
```

wwwwwwwwwr ttttttttttt rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyr rriuoeggn ryyyyyy ryj klrtp;irptiml;rtkroitlrktrpotilr;gkawpeti;lrkgwptjkrotkw;'rtoi4p[tok

Comment: Are you sure your browser supports `break-word`? It's a CSS3 value (http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/).

Answer (score 1):

Browsers can only break words on whitespace characters. So you need to provide some in your long word.

One option is to insert `&shy;` every 10 characters. This will (should) not display if the word fits into a line.

Comment: i have provided a text area for the user to add some description and iam capturing tat desc and placing it in a label .i dont want to display using textarea as i was asked to.Whts the fix for it

Comment: I don't understand what you want to "fix". What is your goal?

Comment: i want to knw how can i break a long text incase if the user enters something of this sort
wwwwwwwwwr ttttttttttt rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyr rriuoeggn ryyyyyy ryj klrtp;irptiml;rtkroitlrktrpotilr;gkawpeti;lrkgwptjkrotkw;'rtoi4p[tok

Comment: As I said in my answer: Search for long words and insert "&shy;" every 10 characters.

Comment: Here's a good [article](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/shy.html) about the soft hyphen "&shy;"

Comment: A similar solution would be using some sort of JS library for this, like: http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/